# Remove percentile (%) from imported string and define string as decimal

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to create a Google Sheet to keep track of some small-time investing that I do.

I use the following formula to import dividend yields from Marketbeat

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.marketbeat.com/stocks/NYSE/MMM/dividend/",
 "//*[@id='cphPrimaryContent_tabDividendHistory']/div[1]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]")
```

See below what the source page looks like. The above formula returns `3.44%`

[image]:

What I need is to only have `3.44`, so that I can calculate with it.

How can I trim the `%` away without having to call the Marketbeat page twice? (Twice: because normally I would trim using `=REPLACE(A2,LEN(A2),1,"")` but `A2` here would be the `IMPORTXML` and I don't want to call it twice).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(IMPORTXML(
 "https://www.marketbeat.com/stocks/NYSE/MMM/dividend/",
 "//*[@id='cphPrimaryContent_tabDividendHistory']/div[1]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]"), 
 "(.+)%")
```

and to turn it into a numeric number you can multiply it by *1